# When using Yad, can a button be made the default?

Tags: bash, yad

The title sets the question.
If it can, what is the coding?
Present coding is:-
yad --center --on-top --text-align=center --buttons-layout=center --title ${0##*/} --width=150 --height=60 --text "Do you want tea?" --button=gtk-no:1 --button=gtk-yes:0
I want to make the yes button the default, so even if I just close the box the yes button is selected.
Many thanks
John

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that $? for Yes=0, for No=1 and Close=252,
so coding externally allowed to make the Yes button
the default.
:-

```
if [[ $? == 0 || $? == 252 ]]
then
echo "Default"
else
echo "No"
fi
```

Comment: Is there a way to make a particular button (or field) the selection default, ie you just hit return and that default selected button is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

This snippet launch a default icon in the systray:

```
yad --notification xxx
```